# uWSGI + Nginx don't generate the .sock file

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm trying to deploy a Django app with uWSGI and Nginx like I always have done in the last 10 years but this time don't seem to work. Looks like there are permissions issues because **the app.sock file is not created**.

This is my uwsgi.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service

[Service]
ExecStart=uwsgi --emperor /app/app/deployment/uwsgi.ini
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is my uwsgi.ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
# Ruta a la raiz del proyecto Django
chdir               = /app/app

# Ruta al archivo wsgi.py del proyecto Django
wsgi-file           = /app/app/app/wsgi.py

# Ruta al virtualenv del proyecto Django
home                = /app/app/.venv

# Process-related settings
master              = true
processes           = %k
threads             = %(%k * 3)

# The socket (use the full path to be safe)
socket              = /tmp/app.sock
chmod-socket        = 660
chown-socket        = debian:www-data
uid                 = www-data
gid                 = www-data

# Clear environment on exit
vacuum              = true

# Location of log files
logto               = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log

# Respawn processes after serving 5000 
max-requests        = 5000

touch-chain-reload  = %dreload
listen              = 40000
cpu-affinity        = 1
max-fd              = 200000
memory-report       = 1
post-buffering      = 1
```

This is my nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name  200.100.000.000;  # Nuestro dominio o direccion IP
    charset utf-8;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/app.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/app.error.log;

    client_max_body_size 10M;  # Tamaño maximo de archivos que podremos subir al servidor

    location /media  {
        # MEDIA_ROOT de nuestro proyecto de Django
        alias /app/app/media;
    }

    location /static {
        # STATIC_ROOT de nuestro proyecto de Django
        alias /app/app/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/app.sock;
        include /app/app/deployment/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

This is the error in the Nginx Error log:

```
2023/06/27 21:26:29 [crit] 948#948: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 90.106.98.100], server: 200.180.100.100, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/app.sock:", host: "200.180.100.100"
```

This is the journalctl and systemctl status uwsgi:

```
Jun 27 21:42:19 vmi.server.net uwsgi[1012]: [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /app/app/deployment/uwsgi.ini
Jun 27 21:42:19 vmi.server.net uwsgi[937]: Tue Jun 27 21:42:19 2023 - [emperor] curse the uwsgi instance /app/app/deployment/uwsgi.ini>
Jun 27 21:42:19 vmi.server.net uwsgi[937]: Tue Jun 27 21:42:19 2023 - [emperor] removed uwsgi instance /app/app/deployment/uwsgi.ini
Jun 27 21:43:04 vmi.server.net uwsgi[1015]: *** has_emperor mode detected (fd: 6) ***
Jun 27 21:43:04 vmi.server.net uwsgi[1015]: [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /app/app/deployment/uwsgi.ini
Jun 27 21:43:04 vmi.server.net uwsgi[937]: Tue Jun 27 21:43:04 2023 - [emperor] curse the uwsgi instance /app/app/deployment/uwsgi.ini>
Jun 27 21:43:04 vmi.server.net uwsgi[937]: Tue Jun 27 21:43:04 2023 - [emperor] removed uwsgi instance /app/app/deployment/uwsgi.ini
```

The app.sock file is not created. The owner of the path /app and all its subfolders is www-data:www-data. **If I execute `sudo uwsgi --socket /tmp/app.sock --home /app/app/.venv --chdir /app/fastlane/ --wsgi-file /app/app/app/wsgi.py` manually as a root it is works, but not with the uwsgi service.**